# Regex for alternating indexes from a word boundary

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I've just finished [this programming challenge on CodeWars](http://www.codewars.com/kata/weird-string-case/javascript):

> Write a function `toWeirdCase` that accepts a string, and returns the same string with all even indexed characters in each word upper cased, and all odd indexed characters in each word lower cased. The indexing just explained is zero based, so the zero-ith index is even, therefore that character should be upper cased.

I tried to figure this out with regex before giving up and simply using a `for` loop with indexes. Just to confirm, the index of capitalising letters resets to 0 whenever there is a space. So `ThIs Is A CoRrEcT AnSwEr` but `ThIs iS nOt`, because every first letter of each word must be capitalised.

With that in mind, is there an approach to look for alternate (odd or even) indexes using regex? In this case, find a word boundary using `\b`, and then every even index from there, until the end of the word?

Answer (score 1):

You can borrow [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to convert apply a function to each character, `i`[`%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder)`2` to detect if `i` is odd, and [`toLowerCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) or [`toUpperCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase) to change the case:

```
function toWeirdCase(str) {
  return [].map.call(str, function(char, i) {
    return char[i%2 ? 'toLowerCase' : 'toUpperCase']();
  }).join('');
}
```

There are multiple ways to reset the index at each space. For example,

```
function toWeirdCase(str) {
  var i = 0;
  return [].map.call(str, function(char) {
    if(char === ' ') i = -1;
    return char[i++ % 2 ? 'toLowerCase' : 'toUpperCase']();
  }).join('');
}
```

Comment: This doesn't match the spec, which is that the index is supposed to relative to the **word**.

Comment: @torazaburo You scared me, I understood you mean it doesn't match the ECMAScript spec.

Answer (score 1):

The function parameter to replace receives the match offset after the matched string and matched groups.

```
function toWeirdCase(s) {
  return s.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g, function (ltr, offset) {
    return offset & 1 ? ltr.toLowerCase() : ltr.toUpperCase();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the input into words, then weird case each word:

```
function  toWeirdCase(str) {
    return str.split(' ').map(weirdCaseWord).join(' ');
}
```

`weirdCaseWord` can be written as in the other answer:

```
function weirdCaseWord(str) {
  return str.split('').map(function(char, i) {
    return char[i%2 ? 'toLowerCase' : 'toUpperCase']();
  }).join('');
}
```

If you prefer, you could use a single map with a flag which is toggled on each character, and reset on a space:

```
function toWeirdCase(str) {
  var even = false;
  return str.split('').map(function(char) {
    even = char === ' ' ? false : !even;
    return char[even ? 'toUpperCase' : 'toLowerCase']();
  }).join('');
}
```